# how to connect powershell to remote exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I have a powershell script that is checking a mailbox in a remote exchange. My script is called several times per second.

At the moment I can connect to the exchange importing the session but it takes a few seconds to download the Exchange cmdlets.

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<FQDN of Exchange 2010 server>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session
```

Is there a fastest way I can run my powershell commands towards exchange?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import the session.  Once you have the session established, you can run Exchange cmdlets against that session immediately using Invoke-Command.